# How to convert a array of objects into string in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, pug

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    House_Name: 'Merlin 5th Avenue',
    no_of_rooms: 6,
    Cost: 3400000,
    PropertyId: 2
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    House_Name: 'Presidential Building',
    no_of_rooms: 5,
    Cost: 3500000,
    PropertyId: 106
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    House_Name: 'GreenSlide Building',
    no_of_rooms: 4,
    Cost: 6300000,
    PropertyId: 107
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    House_Name: 'RabindraNath Building',
    no_of_rooms: 4,
    Cost: 5500000,
    PropertyId: 108
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    House_Name: 'CityView Apartment',
    no_of_rooms: 3,
    Cost: 4300000,
    PropertyId: 109
  }
]
```

I have this array of objects that I want to convert to string so that I can pass it in the get request to some other page. How can I convert the array of objects to string.
The number of objects in the array is dynamic and can change. The array shown above is just one example.

Is there any other way to pass array in a get request?

I am passing the array into a jade file, which then calls a get request?

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    title Property List
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/prop-list-style.css')
    link(href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/likeButton.css')

  body
    // partial:index.partial.html  https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10
    .main
      h1(data-text='Property List') Property List
      - var prop = props
         ul.cards
             for pip in prop
                li.cards_item
                    .card
                        .card_image
                            img(src='https://picsum.photos/500/300/?image=10')
                        .card_content
                            h2.card_title #{pip.House_Name}
                            p.card_text #{pip.no_of_rooms} BHK
                              a(href='/signIn/interested?id=#{pip.PropertyId}&cid=#{customerid}&values=#{properties}') 
                                i.like-button.fa.fa-2x.fa-heart-o(class='#{like}')
                            p.card_text Price: #{pip.Cost}
                            a(href='/signIn/readMore?id=#{pip.PropertyId}&cid=#{customerid}&values=#{properties}')
                                button.btn.card_btn Find Out More
             else 
                h2 No such property exist
    script(src='/javascripts/likebutton.js')

    // partial
```

The #{properties} variable is the variable which holds the array and is a part of the get request.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this code for converting array of objects in to string

first assign the array of objects to a variable and then use json.stringify() method to convert array of objects in to string

```
var random = [{},{},{}.....];

JSON.stringify(random);
```

and to convert string back to array of objects use

```
JSON.parse(random);
```

And also you are making the array of objects wrongly it should be like this and then the above stringify and parse method will work completely fine.

```
        [
          {
            House_Name: 'Merlin 5th Avenue',
            no_of_rooms: 6,
            Cost: 3400000,
            PropertyId: 2
          },
          {
            House_Name: 'Presidential Building',
            no_of_rooms: 5,
            Cost: 3500000,
            PropertyId: 106
          },
          {
            House_Name: 'GreenSlide Building',
            no_of_rooms: 4,
            Cost: 6300000,
            PropertyId: 107
          },
          {
            House_Name: 'RabindraNath Building',
            no_of_rooms: 4,
            Cost: 5500000,
            PropertyId: 108
          },
          {
            House_Name: 'CityView Apartment',
            no_of_rooms: 3,
            Cost: 4300000,
            PropertyId: 109
          }
        ]
```

Comment: JSON.stringify() didn't convert array to string!

Comment: Just to add, ```JSON.stringify``` takes more arguments as well. ```JSON.stringify(object, null, 4) ``` will indent your JSON with 4 spaces. You can select which keys to stringify by passing object in place of ```null```

Comment: Skip the indentation. The target system will rebuild the JS object for processing anyway. For inspection/debugging you will use tools that pretty-print json payload without user intervention.

Comment: @AshutoshViramgama The array of objects is not wrong! It is what is shown when i print the array in console. The array of objects is the result returned after a MySQL query